# .htaccess rewrite to convert forward slash (/) to dash (-)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I need a simple rule to rewrite

- domainn.com/section/page

to

- domain.com/section-page.html

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1-$2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1-$2.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^`([a-z0-9]+)`/`([a-z0-9]+)`/?$ `$1-$2`.html [`QSA`,L]

If you would like to forward your users so the URL shows the change, place R=301 before QSA. `R` = Redirect, `301` = Permanent.